# Silhoutte coefficient- Information retrieval

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval

I have been trying to get my hands dirty with Information Retrieval.My professor gave us this problem to solve, but I can't get my way around it. The matrix given, if it is a distance matrix, the diagonal elements should all be 0. But in the table, they're given as 1. The other entries are also less than 1. How is this possible? Can someone please explain?

Please see question 5.c. I could not enter the table manually and apologize for that.

[image]

Comment: How I interpret it, the value of 1 represents the similarity of the documents. So the diagonal which compares a document to itself should all be 1, this says all documents are exactly similar to themselves. As for the rest of the question I have no idea. // To make the diagonal 0, subtract 1 from the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In every similarity measurement, 1 means totally similar and 0 means there is no similarity between documents.